# Installing Lubuntu 15.04 and stops with error shown in photo

Tags: system-installation, 15.04, lubuntu, acpi, error-handling

I downloaded Lubuntu 15.04 and am installing it on a Toshiba laptop with Core 2 Duo and 2Gb ram. I tried "Try Lubuntu" and "Install Lubuntu" and both give the same error.

It shows (see pic also):

```
[ 0.281313] pci 0000:02:00.0: unsupported pm cap regs version (7)
[ 6.647605] acpi pcc probe failed
```

The first set of numbers are different every time but the rest is always the same.

The hard drive has Win XP home and is still bootable when I take out the Lubuntu CD.

Any ideas of what is wrong would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adwanced power management error,some device use 7 version not supported by kernel.Try to disable it in bios or mount driver for it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? It is not very clear.